# Llenar formulario que está en otra Web utilizando Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, bootstrap-4

lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente, estoy realizando una web donde necesito llenar un formulario que esta en una web externa mediante un formulario en mi web.

Ejemplo, desde mi web quiero buscar algo utilizando para esto el formulario de www.google.com, o sea desde mi web pasarle los datos de búsqueda a este formulario y de ahí me muestre lo que responde dicho proceso, nuevamente en mi web.
Gracias por adelantado por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pues podrias hacer varias cosas:

1. Un iframe (de html) a la web donde vas a hacer el formulario. El problema es que asi no se como podrias coger la respuesta y meterla en tu web, porque la verias en el iframe.
2. Creas el formulario en tu web, y que cuando clickas en "post" llame a una funcion que envia una peticion con requests (por ejemplo) a la url donde esta el formulario (seria una POST con form/data). Luego el resultado lo salvas en tu server y lo visualizas. El problema de esto es que si el formulario en la otra web se actualiza, debes actualizar tambien el tuyo y aniadir o quitar campos, en cambio con la iframe ves siempre lo que haya en la otra web.